# Swift - async call within tableView cellForRowAt

Tags: swift, uitableview, asynchronous, return-value

I tried entering and leaving a DispatchGroup but couldn't quite get that to work.

I am not loading images, so I don't think I need `URLSession.shared.dataTask` with `completionHandler`

In the `cellForRowAt` function, I've called out to another function to do the async loading and return me the values needed to fill in the cell.

```
//in cellForRowAt:
let (value1, value2) = getValues(forRow: indexPath.row)



func getValues(forRow: Int) -> (Int, Int) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        var value1 = 0
        var value2 = 0

        //calculations to figure out the values

        return (value1, value2)
    }
}
```

The `DispatchQueue.main.async` line is giving me an error of `"Cannot convert return expression of type '()' to return type '(Int, Int)'"`

Is there a best way to return a value to a particular tableview cell after an async calculation?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You cannot do _anything_ asynchronously inside `cellForRowAt`. Asynchronous involve the passage of time. But `cellForRowAt` must return the cell _immediately_.

Comment: Also `main.async` is not asynchronous in the way you mean. It is on the main thread, so you are not doing any calculation in the background.

Comment: right, my bad on `main.async` as opposed to a background thread. If the cell must return immediately, I will stick with that. Any suggestions here? Would it be possible to update some of the cell values after `cellForRowAt` has already been completed, once I have my calculations completed in the background?

Comment: Absolutely. The standard procedure is to update the _data model_ asynchronously and call `reloadData()` when you're done doing that. This calls `cellForRowAt` again, and this time the data is there and can be popped into the cell instantly.

Answer (score 1):

`DispatchQueue.main.async` is a void block. You can't return value at the end of it.

You need to invoke a block inside it, to get your values

```
func getValues(forRow: Int, block:(Int,Int)->Void) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        var value1 = 0
        var value2 = 0

        //calculations to figure out the values

        block(value1, value2)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm getting "Attribute can only be applied to types, not declarations" on the @escaping line

Comment: then remove the @escaping